# WooCommerce somehow preventing AJAX requests from returning?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I can't make heads or tails of this. We have a script in `functions.php` that adds products to cart via AJAX:

```
function add_to_cart() {
    $multipleProducts = $_POST['multipleProducts'];

    $productsArray = $_POST['productsArray'];

    foreach ($productsArray as $product) {
        $product_id = apply_filters('woocommerce_add_to_cart_product_id', absint($product[0]));
        $quantity = empty($_POST['quantity']) ? 1 : wc_stock_amount($product[1]);

        \WC()->cart->add_to_cart($product_id, $quantity, null, []);
    }

    error_log('help!!!');
    echo '200';
    wp_die();
}
```

The `error_log` logs fine, meaning the code actually gets that far. However, it just never `echo`es anything or returns anything. No response, no error, just sends and never receives.

If I move the `error_log` and `echo` to above the `foreach`, everything works okay.

Has anyone seen this happen before? I didn't really think it was possible.

Comment: Could you please add just a little more context to this? because judging by the code and how you describe it, it makes no sense. Please give us the php code used to add the ajax action for WP (did you used _nopriv and the standard one?) together with the JS code that triggers/receive the answer for that ajax

Answer (score 0):

The `WC_Cart` `add_to_cart()` method returns the cart item key when a product is successfully added to cart or `false` if not, so you could try to change your code to something like:

```
function add_to_cart() {
    if ( isset($_POST['multipleProducts']) && isset($_POST['productsArray']) ) :
    
    $multipleProducts = $_POST['multipleProducts'];
    $productsArray    = $_POST['productsArray'];
    $response         = []; // Initializing

    foreach ($productsArray as $product) {
        $product_id = apply_filters('woocommerce_add_to_cart_product_id', absint($product[0]));
        $quantity = empty($_POST['quantity']) ? 1 : wc_stock_amount($product[1]);

        $cart_item_key = WC()->cart->add_to_cart($product_id, $quantity, null, []);
        
        $status = $cart_item_key ? 'success' : 'failed';
        
        $response[] = array(
            'product_id'    => $product_id,
            'quantity'      => $quantity,
            'cart_item_key' => $cart_item_key,
            'status'        => $status
        );
    }

    error_log(print_r( $response, true ));
    echo json_encode($response);
    wp_die();
    endif;
}
```

It could works…